# ASP Error and IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, iis-6, ado

In IIS 6 ASP errors were displayed with the line number and a description of the problem. For example,

```
{call dbo.spGetCommunityInfo(xx)} 
Microsoft SQL Native Client error '80020005' 
Invalid character value for cast specification 
/communitydetail.asp, line 42
```

IIS 7 changes the way ASP errors are handled and displays something a lot less helpful. For example,

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request
```

Does anyone know what configuration changes are required to get the behavior of IIS 6 in IIS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AppCmd to turn on ScriptErrorSentToBrowser (it's false in IIS7 defaults, it was true in IIS6). AppCmd live in %SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv and you need to run it as admin:

> appcmd.exe set config
>   -section:system.webServer/asp -ScriptErrorSentToBrowser:true